# MacPorts and the bash PATH

Tags: bash, macports

I am using 10.8.1 (Mountain Lion).

After upgrading to Mountain Lion, some of my MacPorts stopped working. For an easier life, I simply cleared out `/opt/local/` and reinstalled the latest version of MacPorts, followed by the ports themselves.

This has had the side-effect that many of the ports I was using have gone back to their bundled OS X defaults. I opened up `.profile` to make sure that `/opt/local/bin` came first in the PATH, but that hasn't solved the problem.

I suspect the output of `port select` is a symptom:

```
$ port select python
Available versions for python:
    none (active)  # shouldn't the bundled version be here?
    python27
    python32

$ which python
/usr/bin/python
```

Changing the active port (`sudo port select --set python python27`) solves the problem, but not all ports work with `port select`. Does anyone know what's going on here?

**Edit**: I should clarify that I don't consider this a complete fix - you're supposed to be able to change back to the Apple version with a command like `sudo port select --set python python25-apple`, which I suspect I'll only get back by solving the underlying problem.

For the record, the contents of `~/.profile`:

```
export PATH=/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin:/usr/texbin
```

Comment: How about `.bashrc`? I can't remember which is executed first on OS X.

Comment: `$ open .bashrc` gives `The file /Users/ben/.bashrc does not exist`, so apparently that's not it!

Comment: You've solved the python issue.  What other ports still don't work?  What does `echo $PATH` show in your terminal session?  Did you open a new terminal window?  Do you have a `.bash_profile` file along with `.profile`?  If so, the former will be preferred by bash.

Comment: try source ~/.profile, or open a new Terminal.app window. Try: echo $PATH for the current value of the PATH.

Comment: @NedDeily `$ echo $PATH` gives me the PATH as it was written in `.profile`. I don't have a `.bash_profile` file. I have quite a few ports, many of them do work but a few don't. I think most, if not all, of the ones that don't work are Python-related: pip, ipython, etc

Comment: It could be because I have versions of these packages installed on the bundled version of Python, but MacPorts is supposed to not interfere with these, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without more information, it's hard to guess what behavior you are seeing and what you expect to see. MacPorts does provide `port select` options for some of the commands you mention like `python` and `ipython` but [does not yet for pip](http://trac.macports.org/ticket/36178).  In general, MacPorts installs Python scripts with version-specific suffixes, so independent of `port select` options, you should find those commands with their suffix, for example:

```
$ port select --list ipython
Available versions for ipython:
    ipython27
    ipython32 (active)
    none
$ which ipython
/opt/local/bin/ipython
$ which ipython-2.7
/opt/local/bin/ipython-2.7
$ port select --list pip
Warning: Unable to get active selected version: The specified group 'pip' does not exist.
Error: The 'list' command failed: The specified group 'pip' does not exist.
$ which pip
$ which pip-2.7
/opt/local/bin/pip-2.7
```

BTW, neither `pip` nor `ipython` are supplied by Apple with OS X system Pythons, so it's not clear what you mean by bundled OS X defaults.  Perhaps you installed versions of these to the system Python 2.7.  If so, by default, you would see them with `/usr/bin/python2.7` and/or installed in `/usr/local/bin` and `/Library/Python/2.7`.

**Update:** Until MacPorts provides a `port select pip` option (as requested in the MacPorts issue linked above), you should be able to have `pip` execute the MacPorts version by modifying your `.profile` to add the Python framework bin directory at the head of the paths:

```
export PATH=/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/bin:/opt/local/bin:...
```

**Update 2014-04:** MacPorts now does provide a `port select pip` option so you should no longer need to do the `PATH` hack.

```
$ sudo port select pip
Available versions for pip:
    none (active)
    pip27
    pip33
$ sudo port select pip pip27
Selecting 'pip27' for 'pip' succeeded. 'pip27' is now active.
$ hash
$ which pip
/opt/local/bin/pip
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. What further information would you like me to provide? I installed pip and ipython onto the bundled Python myself. I'd like to be able to, for example, run the MacPorts version of pip by default, by simply typing `$ pip`.

Comment: I was expecting this behaviour because MacPorts (`/opt/local`) comes first in the PATH.

Comment: Thanks for the update. That's solved most of the problems I was having.

Comment: @Shoan, the `PATH` manipulation should no longer be necessary. See the updated answer and thanks for the memory jog.

Comment: @NedDeily In my case, I installed an app via pip which installed into the executable to `/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin`. Hence `port select` would not have worked for me.

Comment: @Shoan, yes, that case isn't covered by a default `install` (pip, easy_install, or setup.py) with a framework Python without overriding the Distutils settings (https://docs.python.org/3/install/index.html#location-and-names-of-config-files).

Comment: @NedDeily, I don't know why but this is not working for me. I still get an error when running "sudo port select --list python": Warning: Unable to get active selected version: The specified group 'python' does not exist.
Error: The 'list' command failed: The specified group 'python' does not exist.

Comment: @DennyCrane, do you have an up-to-date MacPorts installation?  `sudo port version` -> `Version: 2.3.1`.  Have you installed at least one MacPorts Python port?  `sudo port installed | grep python` -> `[...] python27 @2.7.8_1 (active) python34 @3.4.1_0 (active)`