# How to change pip3 command to be pip?

Tags: pip

I uninstalled `pip`, and I installed `pip3` instead. Now, I want to use `pip3` by typing `pip` only. The reason is I am used to type `pip` only and every guide uses the `pip` command, so every time I want to copy and paste commands, I have to modify `pip` to `pip3` which wastes time. When I type `pip` I have an error which is `pip: command not found` which means `pip` command is not taken. Is it possible to make `pip` points to `pip3`?

Comment: please consider my answer, that, I think, is proper than an alias

Comment: As an aside, for this specific case, I'd consider using `virtualenv`.

Comment: `alias` or `symlink` is one option, but I think going with `update-alternatives` would be better. Since, you don't want to _update_ your `.bashrc` file time and again, nor make a bunch of **symlinks** for similar cases such as for `python3` and its different versions.

Answer (score 176, accepted):

You can use pip3 using the alias pip by adding alias to your [.bashrc](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/129143/what-is-the-purpose-of-bashrc-and-how-does-it-work) file.

```
alias pip=pip3
```

or by adding a symlink named pip to your [$PATH](https://askubuntu.com/questions/551990/what-does-path-mean), which points to the pip3 binary.

If there is no ~/.bashrc in your home directory on macOS, inputting

```
alias pip=pip3
```

in your ~/.zprofile file has the same effect.

Comment: How can I find ~/.bashrc? I retagged my post based on your recommendation.

Comment: @Ambitions actually, this only concerns Linux/*nix (Mac including), so if you're using Windows, I can't help you. In unix based systems ~ stands for home directory (or if you don't use BASH it may be some other file like .zshrc )

Comment: This does the trick for me in Ubuntu 18.04 as the .bashrc checks for .bash_aliases existence:

`alias pip=pip3 >> ~/.bash_aliases`

Comment: alias pip=pip3 >> ~/.bash_aliases worked for me, thank you TeddybearCrisis

Comment: @Ambitions For MacOS, goto Macintosh HD/Users/yourname/ directory. Putting this alias in any .bashrc or .bash_profile would work.

Comment: This is the wrong answer. And a bad approach. The correct way would be to use `update-alternatives`. Check @c-z's answer.

Comment: @Qumber do you really think that "right approach" is the one that works only on select Linux distributions and requires root privileges?

Comment: Technically `alias pip="pip3"`

Comment: it worked for me well, but whe I input the command inside a `bash` file I still receive a `pip: command not found` error

Answer (score 137):

Rather than manually creating your own alias in bash and hoping this doesn't conflict with anything, most package managers should allow you to register the version you wish to use whilst maintaining dependencies.

For instance on Linux:

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/pip pip /usr/bin/pip3 1
```

Or on Mac (MacPorts):

```
port select --set pip pip3
```

Comment: Selecting 'pip3' for 'pip' failed: The specified group 'pip' does not exist.

Comment: @user3424037 Could be an older version of MacPorts (which didn't support this - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12557114/macports-and-the-bash-path), or Pip has been installed by a method other than MacPorts.

Comment: @ndemarco As far as I'm aware it just creates a link and then tracks that link to make sure it is updated when the application is updated, removed when the application is removed, and doesn't conflict with another application. The technical details of this process I'm not sure of and probably depend on the package manager. I've found Macports in particular is quite good at handling different versions of Python side-by-side, keeping the binaries separate but helpfully telling the user to (re-)run the `--set` command if they'd like to change the default version that is used.

Comment: I can confirm that the Linux statement works. Best answer. Why change the .bashrc with alias like the accepted answer suggests, this here seems more professional.

Comment: questionto42, more professional (update-alternatives) and easier to be automated, I would say... the other solution I would say it is more error-prone. Agree, this should be the selected answer.

Comment: Now just do pip3 install --upgrade pip that will remove pip2, if you are lucky! Case here on Debian Testing! Python 2 is gone.

Answer (score 27):

### Solution 1

Check which version pip is pointing to

```
pip --version
pip 18.0 from /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip (python 2.7)
```

If your `pip` is pointing to `pip2`, locate where is the pip "binary".

```
which pip
/usr/bin/pip
```

This is a simple python script:

```
cat /usr/bin/pip
#!/usr/bin/python2

# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import re
import sys

from pip._internal import main

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.argv[0] = re.sub(r'(-script\.pyw?|\.exe)?$', '', sys.argv[0])
    sys.exit(main())
```

So just change the shebang from `#!/usr/bin/python2` to `#!/usr/bin/python3`.

Now `pip` is pointing to `pip3`.

```
pip --version         
pip 18.0 from /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip (python 3.6)
```

### Solution 2

Remove `/usr/bin/pip` make make a symbolic link from the wanted pip version to it instead.

```
sudo rm /usr/bin/pip
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/pip3.6 /usr/bin/pip
```

Comment: re: Solution 2, It's worthwhile to note that since El Capitan you have to use `sudo ln -s /usr/bin/pip3 /usr/local/bin/pip` (you might have to `sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/bin` first if `/usr/local/bin` doesn't exist) see: stackoverflow.com/a/36734569/2764290

Answer (score 19):

You can install `pip` after install `pip3` by the below command:

```
pip3 install --upgrade pip
```

after that:

```
~ pip --version
pip 20.0.2 from /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip (python 3.8)
```

Comment: It works only for current user:
$ which pip - >
~/.local/bin/pip

Answer (score 15):

Since you uninstalled `pip`, this solution assumes you're only going to use `pip3`.

1. Open your terminal.
2. Create a simple link. To do that type:

   `sudo ln -s /usr/bin/pip3 /usr/bin/pip`

Now when you type `pip`, it will invoke `pip3`.

Check that it worked by typing `pip --version`

```
pip --version   
pip 9.0.1 from /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (python 3.6)
```

You're all set!

Comment: It worked for me, besides I need to "rm -rf /usr/local/bin/pip" first.

Comment: It's worthwhile to note that since El Capitan you have to use `sudo ln -s /usr/bin/pip3 /usr/local/bin/pip` (you might have to `sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/bin` first if `/usr/local/bin` doesn't exist) see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36734569/2764290

Answer (score 13):

You can write pip for pip3 after changing bashrc file in the home directory.

In mac -

Open bashrc file -

```
vim ~/.bashrc
```

Add this line at the end of the file -

```
alias pip="pip3"
```

Close the file. Don't forget to source this file in the terminal by

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

You are good to go. Now, whenever you will use pip in any command. it will be interpreted as pip3

You can check it by running the command -

```
pip --version
```

Comment: This repeats the core solution of the accepted answer of MacHala. A bit looking at the posting dates: Though this answer explains a bit more what to do with it, I do not see an upvote here for an answer 2 years after the accepted answer. A comment / edit would have done it. Apart from that. The probably best answer is that of @cz which was also before this one.

Answer (score 6):

Pip is installed in /usr/bin/. If you don't have pip at all, I would suggest to install pip3 only. Make sure you don't need older version.

You can check available pip versions using following command.

> ls /usr/bin/pip*

If you have multiple pip you need to prioritize your pip versions. I had only pip3 so I add it to the first priority. You can use following command and it is done.

> sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/pip pip /usr/bin/pip3 1

You will get output as :

> update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/pip3 to provide /usr/bin/pip (pip) in auto mode

Test now:

> pip --version

You will get:
pip 18.1 from /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip (python 3.7)

If you have other version for python2.7, you can use same update command and change last digit 1 to 2. This will make it second priority.

Answer (score 4):

I believe one shouldn't do such a thing. Actually I would argue it's even better to not use the `pip`, `pip3`, etc. scripts ever. Instead one should always prefer the more explicit and surefire way of using *pip*'s executable module for one specific Python interpreter:

```
path/to/pythonX.Y -m pip somecommand
```

References:

- https://snarky.ca/why-you-should-use-python-m-pip/
- https://snarky.ca/a-quick-and-dirty-guide-on-how-to-install-packages-for-python/

Comment: I was happy to have this answer remind me that, even though I installed `pip3` via my package manager (`apt`) rather than `python -m ensurepip` (which wasn't available on my distro), once `pip3` is installed, `python -m pip` works (assuming that python points to my python3).

Answer (score 2):

This can be done by simply creating an alias for the command. 
To create an alias just type

`$alias new_command="existing_command"`
In your case,
`$alias pip="pip3"`

Although this isn't permanent. OT make it permanent edit your bashrc file
`$ vim ~/.bashrc`
an to the end of it append the line. 
`$alias pip="pip3"`

Answer (score 2):

It depends on how you manage your python versions (system, brew, pyenv, ...) and which python installation you are currently using.

For example if you use brew then creating a simlink is a good option:

```
ln -s -f /usr/local/bin/pip3 /usr/local/bin/pip
```

validate that pip uses the correct version:

```
which pip
```

will give you

```
/usr/local/bin/pip
```

Answer (score 0):

Open the shell configuration file (such as .bashrc or .bash_profile) in a text editor.
For example open it with **nano** `sudo nano .bash_profile` or with **vim** `vim .bash_profile`.

Add this function, which checks if pip3 exists and pass all the arguments received by the pip function to pip3:

```bash
function pip {
    if [[ $(which pip3) ]]; then
        pip3 "$@"
    else
        echo "pip3 command not found. Make sure Python 3 and pip3 are installed."
    fi
}
```

If **pip3** is not found (i.e., it doesn't exist on your system), it displays an error message indicating that pip3 is not available.

Answer (score -6):

Copy the pip3 file and rename as pip:

```sh
sudo cp /usr/bin/pip3 /usr/bin/pip
pip --version
```

and

```
pip3 --version
```

Works now.

Comment: it's really better to symlink as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56512469/2764290)