# Python3: No module named pip

Tags: python

When i tried entering the command on terminal (Im using Linux): python3 -m pip install -r requirements.txt
I get the error: No module named pip

I have already installed pip on Python3 using: apt-get install python3-pip.

Any help is appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: does just `pip` or `pip3` instead of `python3 -m pip` do anything?

Comment: https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/

Comment: @castis the installer from pypa.io will not necessarily play nicely with Ubuntu packages.

Comment: What's you distro version and package version(s)? This looks like a bug.

Comment: As @Zenville asked, apart from my request, please provide the result of `which python3` and `which pip3`. Your Python may not be the system's stock Python.

Answer (score 0):

`pip3 -V` or `pip3 --version` should return the Python 3 version

Also, make use of `pip3 install -r requirements.txt`

Comment: Yes, but why doesn't `python3 -m pip` work? That should be equivalent to `pip3`.

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev kindly output the results of `which pip` and `which pip3`. It could be path related.

Comment: I'm not the OP. I just pointed out that this doesn't quite answer the question as asked.

Comment: Apologies @ivan_pozdeev.

Comment: Kleiton, you can set an alias for pip with the following link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44455001/how-to-change-pip3-command-to-be-pip

Comment: I figured out the solution (the only one I guess). I have to manually import all the modules due to the pip bug.