# I have to call up pip3 by typing "pip3" and would rather just type "pip" how can I do this?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

e to call up pip3 by typing "pip3" and would rather just type "pip" how can I do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change pip3 command to be pip?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44455001/how-to-change-pip3-command-to-be-pip)

Comment: You need to make an alias (e.g. symlink) for `pip` that points to `pip3`, and set it in your PATH such that it gets resolved first before any other executables called `pip` are found.

Comment: @flakes you could also make a literal alias: `alias pip=pip3` in your bash_profile, e.g.

Comment: What operating system are you on? (Windows/Linux/MacOS)