# Pycharm fialed to install package

Tags: python, selenium, pycharm

I've tried the File>Settings>project>python interperter route as well as right clicking and install package from the context menu but both result in the error below:

```
Usage:   
  /home/pi/git/scrappyApp/venv/bin/python -m pip install [options] <requirement specifier> [package-index-options] ...
  /home/pi/git/scrappyApp/venv/bin/python -m pip install [options] -r <requirements file> [package-index-options] ...
  /home/pi/git/scrappyApp/venv/bin/python -m pip install [options] [-e] <vcs project url> ...
  /home/pi/git/scrappyApp/venv/bin/python -m pip install [options] [-e] <local project path> ...
  /home/pi/git/scrappyApp/venv/bin/python -m pip install [options] <archive url/path> ...

no such option: --build-dir
```

using python 3.7 in a virtualenv ~/git/scrappyApp/venv/bin/python

UPDATE
oddly enough running pip3 install selenium directly from a command prompt worked.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61063676/command-errored-out-with-exit-status-1-python-setup-py-egg-info-check-the-logs
I think I found this by copying and pasting the error into stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you should be using pip3 instead of pip. Like you said in your update:

> [...]running pip3 install selenium directly[...]

Running pip on mac and some distro of linux result in using pip for python prior to python3. You could also set an alias for pip in your bashrc profile like in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44455078/11770022)