# How do I use pip instead of python3 pip on my MAC?

Tags: python, macos, pip, python-3.7

I have python 3 installed on my mac. I have installed packages via `python3 pip install` up until now, but if I try to use `pip install` I'm getting *pip not found* error. How do I resolve this?

p.s: I just want to install packages via pip install and not python3 -m pip install.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change pip3 command to be pip?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44455001/how-to-change-pip3-command-to-be-pip)

Answer (score 1):

You can set alias in your ~/.bash_profile and try

```
alias pip=pip3
#or
alias pip=python3 pip
```

Answer (score 1):

I have found in the end that this is the right way to do it:

https://opensource.com/article/19/5/python-3-default-mac

The actions to take in order to achieve this it's easy.
Take the first 3 steps from the blog.

After that you can install any of versions available from this list, using this command to show it:
`pyenv install -l`

Why you should do this way requires you to read the entire post.

Answer (score 0):

Change alias in your terminal profile file

if you use bash goto ~/.bashrc file and

```
alias pip=pip3
```

if you use zsh goto ~/.zshrc file and do the same

Answer (score 0):

do this on terminal:

```
alias pip=pip3
```

or use :

```
pip3 install <library_name>
```